# Subclassing class that only expose convenience init

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to subclass the UITableViewRowAction class that is declared as follow :

```
class UITableViewRowAction : NSObject, NSCopying {

  convenience init(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle, title: String!, handler: (UITableViewRowAction!, NSIndexPath!) -> Void)

  var style: UITableViewRowActionStyle { get }
  var title: String!
  @NSCopying var backgroundColor: UIColor! // default background color is dependent on style
  @NSCopying var backgroundEffect: UIVisualEffect?
}
```

I would like my subclass to override the convenience init that is present here and call super to get that convenience init.

Here is what I would want to do :

```
public class MySubclass : UITableViewRowAction  {

  let handler : (UITableViewRowAction!, NSIndexPath!) -> Void
  public init(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle, title: String!, handler: (UITableViewRowAction!, NSIndexPath!) -> Void) {
      self.handler = handler
      super.init(style: style, title: title, handler: handler)  // error == Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UITableViewRowAction'
  }
}
```

I want to do this in order to expose the handler as a readonly property to be able to unit test that the handler does what I think it should do.

So my problem is that the super class don't expose the handler passed into the init method and there is no way to set it outside of the init method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answer is really a whole lot different from yours, but I ran into a similar problem as you while trying to unit test.  This *feels* a little cleaner; but that is subjective.  You can use set_AssociatedObject (and get_AssociatedObject) and a small private ActionTrigger wrapper class to allow triggering the action from within a unit test.

```
import UIKit
import ObjectiveC

var ActionTriggerHandle: UInt8 = 0

private class ActionTrigger {
    private var handler: (UITableViewRowAction!, NSIndexPath!) -> ()
    private var action: UITableViewRowAction

    private init(action: UITableViewRowAction, handler: (UITableViewRowAction!, NSIndexPath!) -> Void) {
        self.handler = handler
        self.action = action
    }

    private func trigger(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        handler(action, indexPath)
    }
}

public extension  UITableViewRowAction  {
    public convenience init(title: String!, style: UITableViewRowActionStyle, exposedHandler: (UITableViewRowAction!, NSIndexPath!) -> Void) {
        self.init(style: style, title: title, handler: exposedHandler)
        var actionTrigger = ActionTrigger(action: self, handler: exposedHandler)
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ActionTriggerHandle, actionTrigger, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
    }

    public func trigger(indexPath:NSIndexPath) {
        if let storedActionTrigger = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &ActionTriggerHandle) as? ActionTrigger {
            storedActionTrigger.trigger(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, the setAssociatedObject, will manage the clean up in a more timely manner (correct me if I'm wrong), which will remove the need of my need clean up. However I would return the handler instead of having a trigger method to not impose test code behaviour to production code. But interesting alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot subclass `UITableViewRowAction`.  Consider it a `final` class.  (Objective-C doesn't have a formal way of declaring final classes, but, informally, this class in final due to the lack of a publicly declared initializer.)

If you look at the originating Obj-C code, `UITableViewRowAction` instances can only be created with a class method:

```
+ (instancetype)rowActionWithStyle:(UITableViewRowActionStyle)style
                             title:(NSString *)title
                           handler:(void (^)(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath))handler;
```

(That class method is converted into the convenience initializer you see in Swift.)

`UITableViewRowAction` does not declare any initializers.  Furthermore, its `style` property is readonly and cannot be assigned outside of the class method above.

There is no way to instantiate `UITableViewRowAction` outside of this class method, and therefore no way to subclass `UITableViewRowAction`.

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to add Objective-C code to my application. I've found an ugly walk around, I will post it in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an ugly walk around (code need to be cleaned up).

The walk around involve an extension on the UITableViewRowAction.
Unfortunately, no storage can be added to the instance.
So a static array is added to add storage for the different instance that were created.
But that raise a problem of retain cycle that is broken here by the use of a "WeakWrapper".

I'm open to better suggestion.

```
import UIKit
import FoundationAdditions

public extension  UITableViewRowAction  {

    private static var storedHandlers = [handlerStorage]()
    var handler : ((UITableViewRowAction!, NSIndexPath!) -> Void)! {
        get {
            var needCleanUp = false
            var result = {(a: UITableViewRowAction!, b: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in }
            for storage in UITableViewRowAction.storedHandlers {
                if let x = storage.instance.item {
                    if x === self {
                        result = storage.handler
                        break
                    }
                } else {
                    needCleanUp = true
                }
            }

            if needCleanUp {
                //  DO the CLEAN UP
            }

            return result
        }
    }

    public convenience init(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle, title: String!, storedHandler: (UITableViewRowAction!, NSIndexPath!) -> Void) {
        self.init(style: style, title: title, handler: storedHandler)

        let x = handlerStorage(instance: self, handler: storedHandler)
        UITableViewRowAction.storedHandlers.append(x)
    }
}

private class handlerStorage {
    let instance : WeakWrapper<UITableViewRowAction>
    let handler : ((UITableViewRowAction!, NSIndexPath!) -> Void)

    init(instance: UITableViewRowAction, handler: (UITableViewRowAction!, NSIndexPath!) -> Void) {
        self.instance = WeakWrapper<UITableViewRowAction>(item: instance)
        self.handler = handler
    }
}
```